# Java 11 on dual boot machine - malfunction

Tags: linux, windows-10, java, multi-boot, linux-mint

Something strange is happening. This machine is dual boot to W10 and Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu Xenial). 64-bit machine.

Java 11 works fine in Linux. But twice now I have installed Java 11 in W10 (using the .exe installer) and changed the PATH accordingly.

It works fine initially. But twice, when I've booted to Linux and spent a few hours there (I prefer working in Linux) and then rebooted to W10 an app dependent on Java doesn't work. I then go

```
D:\apps\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin>java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I've consequently reverted to Java 8 on my W10 OS.

I emphasise that I haven't messed around with this location on the D: drive in Linux, although I do mount and use (extensively) that NTFS drive in Linux.

Nothing like this has never happened with Java 8 on W10.

If necessary I suppose I'll have to create another partition in W10 purely for Java 11, and see whether that solves things. I'm hoping to find a rational explanation and maybe even a solution though.

Comment: Have you tried to just reboot W10 without booting Linux in between? Is J11 OK when doing so? Is the J11 runtime defined in the registry (`HKLM/Software/JavaSoft/...`).

Comment: Yes, after the first time this happened (and after I reinstalled J11) I checked rebooting to W10 from W10 - worked fine. In fact I even rebooted to Linux and then rebooted to W10 - worked fine! It is only after several hours on Linux that this seems to happen. I'll have to check later about the other point.